# python to_sql with sql server

Tags: python, sql-server

so - I just want to do to_sql in python, against an sql server.

The following code works fine:

```py
database = pyodbc.connect(f"DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}")
if len( pandas.read_sql( "select 1 as bob", database )) != 1: raise Exception("connection to the database didn't seem to work")
```

but then when I try to_sql - it gives me an error including sqlite_master.   Googling says I need to create an sqlalchemy engine - but I've been unable to do that - when I replace the above code with something like:

```py
database = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://{username}:{password}@{server}/{database}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server", echo = False).connect()
if len( pandas.read_sql( "select 1 as bob", database )) != 1: raise Exception("connection to the database didn't seem to work")
```

I just get various bizarre errors like "Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string" - but if I take the driver bit off - I get "data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Comment: You forgot to mention the actual error in the first case. If you get an error mentioning `sqlite` you're probably using the wrong connection or driver.  The second error is clear - the URL is wrong, quite possibly because the password contains characters that have special meaning in a ULR, like `@`, `?` or `#`

Comment: Have you tried [the SQL Server tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15) for using pyodbc? Try that first to ensure you can connect to the database